# Odoo.sh : Upgrading Github from Personal to Team account

Tags: github, odoo, branch, webhooks, odoo.sh

To work with an external developper, i want to add protection rules on my github-branches (related to my **Odoo.sh - v13**).
For that purpose, i'm considering upgrading Github from my currently "**Personnal Github Account**" to a "**Team Github Account**", which requires to create a new "**Organization account**" in Github (see image in attach):

[image]

As far as I know, during odooSh's installation, 2 elements have been set in my Github account:

• a **Deploy Key**

• a **Webhook** using a **secret**, that is set automatically during installation (unreachable for me)

My Questions:

- Does anyone have any experience about this kind of upgrade and its effect on Deploy Key and Webhooks ?
- Are the settings of my Personnal Account (Deploy Key and Webhooks) automatically copied and pasted in the Organization Account without breaking my OdooSh-system ?
- Does it require an intervention of the Odoo-support ?